# Prevent Deezer connection popup to show automatically

Tags: facebook, api, deezer

I am developing a deezer web application (javascript SDK).

I have a simple "hello world" player (example from the deezer dev website); if I start playing a song I can listen just to the 30 secs preview and it is correct, I am not connected to deezer.

What I want to avoid is the automatic deezer connection popup window which appears just after the music start playing. What I would like to do is instead explaining to the user why she has the 30 sec limit and invite her to connect her deezer account. That automatic popup is very very confusing for the average user. Is there a way to prevent it?

Furthermore: it is still not clear to me WHEN this popup is showed: if I am logged in facebook (not in deezer, just in facebook), the popup is showed, otherwise is not.
In order to do a test, I have DELETED my deezer account (which I registered through facebook) but it seems that when I am logged into facebook the Deezer SDK still remember me and launches the popup...

Does anyone has more information about?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to block that popup. It shows up every time a user needs to register/sign up to stream full tracks (usually after getting the 30 seconds previews). Credentials are cached so if the user is logged in Deezer from another browser window or previous navigation (on Deezer.com or any website using Deezer connect), it won't show up and those credentials will be used.

The only way you can be more proactive about the Deezer registration is to guide your user to your own login button (using DZ.login from the SDK) on your page before getting the popup.

Comment: Guiding the user to DZ connection first is what we do now, but from tests and interviews we discovered that this method is not effective: many users don't get why they have to open a DZ account BEFORE opening an account on our app, and the result is that they just leave the site without registering to DZ.
Giving the user the chance to immediately try the application (with the 30 sec) and then say: ok now you can remove the limit registering to deezer is much more understandable for the avg user. According to the feedaback we received, the connection popup adds confusion to the workflow.

Comment: I still, anyway, don't understand WHEN exactly the connection window is displayed: as said before, if I don't have cookies and I am not logged into facebook, the automatic popup is NOT showed, while it is showed immediately (not at the end of the 30 secs) when I am logged in facebook: does this mean that, even if I deleted my account from deezer, there is still a connection between that account and the facebook account? Or that if the current user is logged in facebbok (deezer user or not) the window is showed? I don't understand the rationale behind this.

Comment: The popup shows up when the user needs to be authenticated to perform an action (all doc available on [Deezer developers](http://developers.deezer.com): adding playlists, streaming more than 30s, etc. Please provide more information about your page (link at least), so we can try to help.

Comment: This is the test:

http://dadabik.org/deezer_test/deezer_test.html
if I click on "play playlist" and I'm not logged in FB: 30 secs, no popup;


If I click on "play playlist" and I'm logged in FB (NOT IN deezer) in another window, POPUP appears immediately